# How to repeat background image in special divided way

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, background-image

I have an image 
(Have no reputation to Post an image but if need will put some link later)

1. Want to repeat it at whole Width of DIV(header for an example), no matter what the size is it.
2. If cut the image on 3 divided parts "left, middle and right", Want middle to be fixed always in center (30px for an example) and rest 2 parts to repeat to left and to right.

   - The first try was to make this picture with 4k pixels and set it with CSS {background:url('images/bg.png') repeat-x center center} but is stupid
   - The second try was to divide it on 3 floated DIVs and make % widths:

There was no so good success and if I use this I would put Absolute positioned elements over this background.

```
div.left_bg{height:59px;width:49%;background:url('../images/left_bg.png') repeat-x center center;float:left;}

div.middle_bg{height:59px;width:2%;background:url('../images/middle_bg.png') repeat-x center center;float:left;}

div.right_bg{height:59px;width:49%;background:url('../images/right_bg.png') repeat-x center center;float:right;}
```

So if there is some trick to make it right please tell it :)

Comment: You can start by reading about CSS for [background](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background)...

Comment: Does this work for your purposes? http://jsfiddle.net/acbabis/hTgm6/. It won't guarantee that the edges of the images line up. If you need this, it can be tweaked.

Comment: @acbabis 
It is  some kind of opposite of your example, I need fixed size middle background and 100% repeatable 1px-width From left to middle part and another 100% repeatable 1px-width From middle part to Right

Comment: This is work at 99% but is good enough. Thank you to everyone who wants to help
  

    <div class="left_bg"></div>
    <div class="right_bg"></div>
    <div class="middle_bg"></div>
    
    div.left_bg{height:59px;width:50%;background:url('../images/left_bg.png') repeat-x center center;float:left;}
    div.middle_bg{height:59px;width:30px;background:url('../images/middle_bg.png') repeat-x center center;margin:0px auto;}
    div.right_bg{height:59px;width:50%;background:url('../images/right_bg.png') repeat-x center center;float:left;}

Comment: Sorry, I misread that. Are you able to use [calc](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc) for this project?

Comment: To be honest I see calc() for a first time now. But if the question is if I care about old style browsers, no I don't. So what is your idea with calc() :) ?

Comment: basically, the width of left and right images should be `width: calc(50%-15px)`. I'll code it up when I have time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is it ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/acbabis/hTgm6/))

HTML

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="background">
        <div class="background-image background-left"></div>
        <div class="background-image background-middle"></div>
        <div class="background-image background-right"></div>
        <div style="clear: both"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="header-content">
        Header Text
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.header {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.background {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.background-image {
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
}

.background-left {
    background-image: url('http://placehold.it/99x50');
    width: calc(50% - 15px);
}

.background-middle {
    background-image: url('http://placehold.it/30x50');
    width: 30px;
}

.background-right {
    background-image: url('http://placehold.it/100x50');
    width: calc(50% - 15px);
}

.header-content {
    position: relative;
}
```